# Is there a way to validate and verify a email address in contact form 7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a website which uses contact form 7 for capturing user data, there is a email field  which needs to be validated as well as verified as a valid user. i came across api which charge you for that. 
My code for  checking the validation is as follows

```
                <!--Email must be a valid  email -->
                jQuery('#contact_email').on('input', function() {
                    var input=jQuery(this);
                    var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
                    var is_email=re.test(input.val());
                    if(is_email){input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid"); jQuery(".not-valid-email").css("visibility","hidden");}
                    else{input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid"); jQuery(".not-valid-email").css("visibility","visible");}
                });
```

how can i also validate if the entered valid email address is also authentic ?

Comment: No there is no such type of validation is available. You can send the activation link to user instead, if user click than you can activate them otherwise no login.

Comment: i am looking for some api or ajax call which provides email verification on the go. By checking if the smtp port is enabled for that particular domain.

Comment: Try this https://verify-email.org/ and the api link is https://verify-email.org/using-api.html

Comment: They don't provide support for javascript .@AnandPandey

Comment: to check if the MX recored exist for a domain, you can use this http://php.net/getmxrr